# maven is unable to find any package from test cases

Tags: java, spring, maven, unit-testing, junit

```
package my.helloworld;

import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class HomeControllerTest {

}
```

The above is my test code. Even this empty code isn't compiling. Below is my pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.helloworld</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-helloworld</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring-helloworld</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>${jdk.version}</source>
      <target>${jdk.version}</target>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- embedded Jetty server, for testing -->
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
    <configuration>
      <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
      <webApp>
        <contextPath>/spring3</contextPath>
      </webApp>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- configure Eclipse workspace -->
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
      <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
      <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
      <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
      <wtpContextName>spring3</wtpContextName>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

now when I run `mvn jetty:run` or `mvn clean install` or `mvn test`, i get the following error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project spring-helloworld: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/kay/Projects/Spring/MVC/HelloWorld/spring-helloworld/src/test/java/my/helloworld/HomeControllerTest.java:[3,1] package org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers does not exist
[ERROR] /home/kay/Projects/Spring/MVC/HelloWorld/spring-helloworld/src/test/java/my/helloworld/HomeControllerTest.java:[7,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Earlier, it was giving error that package org was not found. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The class `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers` you are trying to `import` is part of the `spring-test` module. Add that as a test dependency, because otherwise, it will not be on your classpath and thus, your compiler cannot find it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And if you don't import something that comes from org.*, then the compiler will not find the package org. But to say something more exact about that, we would need the code and preferably the error message.

Comment: I added this, but didn't help

Comment: If you get the same error message, then you didn't add it correctly. Sorry, there not much more to say about this... The class is there since Spring 3.2, so it's unlikely that you've got an old version...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `<scope>test</scope>` to see whether it works then?